# For each day x, for each missing unique value y of column z, create a row with date=x and z=most recent value of y

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark DataFrame that states on which `Date`s an item had what `Stock` in a specific `Size`. The composite key of the table is [Date, Size]. Given the item has `n` sizes, for each date 0 to `n` rows can exist.

```
input = spark.createDataFrame([
    # Day 1: Row for all sizes
    [1, 1, 10],
    [1, 2, 10],
    [1, 3, 10],
    # Day 2: Row for one size
    [2, 1, 8],
    # Day 3: Row for no size
    # Day 4: Row for two sizes
    [4, 1, 7],
    [4, 2, 9],
], ["Date", "Size", "Stock"])
```

For example, on the second day, overall two pieces of the item in size 1 were sold, reducing its stock for this size from 10 to 8. There were no transactions for size 1 or 3 on this day.

I'd like to compute the `Stock` the item had for each of its `Sizes` on each `Date`. The expected output looks like this:

```
expected = spark.createDataFrame([
    # Day 1
    [1, 1, 10],
    [1, 2, 10],
    [1, 3, 10],
    # Day 2
    [2, 1, 8],
    [2, 2, 10],
    [2, 3, 10],
    # Day 3
    [3, 1, 8],
    [3, 2, 10],
    [3, 3, 10],
    # Day 4
    [4, 1, 7],
    [4, 2, 9],
    [4, 3, 10],
], ["Date", "Size", "Stock"])
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to generate a sequence of dates from the min and max date, cross join to get a list of combinations of date and size, left join to the original dataframe, and get the previous stock value using `last` with `ignoreNulls` set to `True`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = input.agg(F.expr('sequence(min(Date), max(Date)) as Date')).select(F.explode('Date').alias('Date'))

result = df.crossJoin(
    input.select('Size').distinct().repartition(10)
).join(
    input, 
    ['Date', 'Size'], 
    'left'
).withColumn(
    'Stock', 
    F.last('Stock', True).over(Window.partitionBy('Size').orderBy('Date'))
)

result.orderBy('Date', 'Size').show()
+----+----+-----+
|Date|Size|Stock|
+----+----+-----+
|   1|   1|   10|
|   1|   2|   10|
|   1|   3|   10|
|   2|   1|    8|
|   2|   2|   10|
|   2|   3|   10|
|   3|   1|    8|
|   3|   2|   10|
|   3|   3|   10|
|   4|   1|    7|
|   4|   2|    9|
|   4|   3|   10|
+----+----+-----+
```